# How many transformations does Chopper have after time skip?

Tags: one-piece

At first, Chopper said that he can transform into 7 different forms using his Rumble Ball:

- Brain Point
- Heavy Point
- Jump Point
- Guard Point
- Horn Point
- Walk Point
- Arm Point

By the time, he also has Monster Point by eating three Rumble Balls at once.

After time skip, he can also transform into his Kung Fu Point. I've so far seen Guard, Brain, Walk, Heavy, Horn, and Monster Point after time skip,
but I think I haven't or have yet to see Chopper transform into his other forms.

Is Chopper have shown to transform into his Arm Point or Jump Point after the time skip?
And is the Kung Fu Point his only new transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, the transformations you mentioned are the only ones that have been shown in the Manga/Anime and any information about him having a new transformation has not yet been revealed, or even hinted at (although it's quite likely).

As per [One Piece wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hito_Hito_no_Mi#Kung_Fu_Point)

> It seems that Kung Fu Point combines the power of Arm Point and the acrobatic skill of Jumping Point though to a lesser degree than each individual point. In this form Chopper has been shown to possess enough strength to easily break down giant steel doors.

This *may* explain why we haven't seen Arm Point or Jump Point after the timeskip.

We haven't seen new transformations of Chopper (except for Kung Fu Point) after the timeskip, but we can note his improvement as:

> Chopper is now able to produce a new "Horn Point" with larger "Stag Beetle" like antlers which are useful for digging in the ground at high speeds, along with a new and improved "Guard Point" which is now able to grow big and strong enough to protect the Thousand Sunny from one of the Kraken's tentacle's. In addition, he is able to utilize those forms without consuming a Rumble Ball; instead, eating a Rumble Ball now allows him to enter his most powerful form, Monster Point, and fight in it for three minutes.
>
> After the timeskip, Chopper has gained the ability to keep control of
>   himself and communicate coherently while in his monster form though
>   his voice is significantly deeper.

Comment: whoaa... Never notice that Kung Fu Point are Arm Point and Jump Point combined! thanks for your information